# Test validity of any kind of (network) proxy in Java

Tags: java, proxy, network-protocols

I checked the standard Java API relating to proxies here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html and it seems very limited.

From the little I know, there are way more protocols supported by proxies than the ones listed in Proxy.Type ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.Type.html ) and some proxies are login/password-protected: I do not see any authentication-related method in java.net.Proxy.

My main use case is to check whether a given proxy is reachable or not. Is there a way to achieve this within the JDK or with a third-party Java library?

Thanks in advance,
Rolf

Comment: As a side note, we're using Install4J but I did not see any proxy-related validation method exposed in their Java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up using org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient. This is not a 100% satisfactory solution, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to connect to the proxy:

```
boolean isReachable = false;
try {
   URL url = new URL( "http://" + proxyHost + ":" + proxyPort );
   url.openStream().close();
   isReachable = true;
}
catch( Throwable t ){
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 
What about password-protected proxies?

Comment: And not all proxies are reachable this way AFAIK.